# Yii2 getting sum of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, yii2

I have 2 tables:

1. `warehouse ['id','warehouse_name']` and
2. `products ['id','product_name','qty','warehouse_id']`

which are connected through `warehouse_id`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need groupBy product_name and sum column qty and warehouse
for example:

`Product 2   14   WH1,WH2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your sample output data, i think your are looking for `SUM` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT p.product_name,
       sum(p.qty) AS qty,
       GROUP_CONCAT(w.warehouse_name
                    ORDER BY w.warehouse_name ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS warehouse
FROM product p
INNER JOIN warehouse w ON p.warehouse_id = w.id
GROUP BY p.product_name;
```

**Result:**

```
product_name    qty     warehouse
------------    ---     ---------
product 2        14     WH1,WH2
product 3        2      WH1
product 5        4      WH3
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TKEV96565)**